Cannot get ubuntu server to resolve to the internet
Hello I have installed ubuntu server 24.04.1 inside virtualbox using a bridged adapter but I cannot get the machine to resolve an internet address.
I tried installing net-tools etc and if congig and pinging 8.8.8.8 but nothing works.
Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted.


Ubuntu Sever does not use network manager.

The commands seem all wrong. Ubuntu server uses (IIRC) systemd networkd with a netplan front end for network config, and nameserver isn't ping.  I'm guessing there's some advanced settings here but the question is where they're done.  I'd look at the /etc/netplan folder first...

sorry but im autistic and on the spectrum so I dont understand your response?

Im still struggling there is no netplan folder I have an etc folder but no netplan folder
